# background-color over on background-image

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I try to add opacity transition on three div with background-image but the opacity have effect on h4 title so i use background-color rgba but the problem is that it doesn't appear over image.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: try image tag instead of background-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution for what you want, but I came to it with a lot of tweaking:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwvGkZ

(note: I only applied it to the element in the middle)

The most important change is that I put the background-images into the CSS stylesheet (not inline style), and as `background` property. Also the background color (applied to `.promo-overlay`) I defined as `background`- that way two the backgrounds can be combined. For more details see the codepen.